# What is the collation used while comparing Unicode string literals in SQL Server 2019?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, collation, encoding

My understanding is that the collation for comparing Unicode string literals is determined by the database collation.

My database is using `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation.

When I compare N'ß' to 'ss', I expect the comparison to fail. But it does not. I am trying to figure out why. Here is the reproduction:

```
    set nocount on 
    go
    use tempdb
    go
    
    SELECT 
       @@version as SqlServerVersion,
       CONVERT(nvarchar(128), SERVERPROPERTY('collation')) as SqlServerCollation,
     DB_NAME() AS DatabaseName
    ,DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') AS CollationUsedBySQLServerDatabase
    GO
    declare @ss varchar(255) = 'ss'
    declare @Nscharfess nvarchar(255) = N'ß'
    declare @scharfess varchar(255) = 'ß'
    
    select case  when @Nscharfess   = @ss then 'Unicode : Strings match' else 'Unicode : Strings do not match' end,
            case when @scharfess    = @ss then 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS : Strings match' else 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS : Strings do not match' end
```

Output:

```
SqlServerVersion
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64) 
Sep 24 2019 13:48:23 
Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 19045: ) (Hypervisor)

SqlServerCollation
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

DatabaseName
tempdb

CollationUsedBySQLServerDatabase
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS


Unicode : Strings match        
SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS : Strings do not match

Completion time: 2024-02-15T00:16:59.1968376-08:00
```

---

I expect 'ß' and 'ss' to match but not if my database is at SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS. I wanted to check if there was a gap in my understanding which currently stands as "For Nvarchar() or Nchar() datatype, the SQL Server grabs the collation from the database setting".  This translates to "my database is at SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and thus the comparison should fail. If it is succeeding, what collation is the SQL Server using? And why?

---

It is still not clear to me. My database is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. SQL Server is expected to use this collation for Unicode as well as non-Unicode data.  I do get it that the non-Unicode comparision 'ß' to 'ss' should fail. Indeed, I expect that. But why does Unicode comparison N'ß' to 'ss' succeed? I am arguing that even the Unicode comparison should have failed as it ought to have been done under `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

Answer (score 8):

> My understanding is that the collation for comparing Unicode string literals is determined by the database collation.

Yes, this is correct. In fact, the local database's default collation is used for comparing both Unicode and non-Unicode string literals (and variables / parameters). This covers the following datatypes: `CHAR`, `VARCHAR` (which covers `'...'` string literals), `NCHAR`, and `NVARCHAR` (which covers `N'...'` string literals). Also, `TEXT` and `NTEXT`, but don't use those as they are deprecated and less functional/performant than their replacements: `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, respectively).

> When I compare N'ß' to 'ss', I expect the comparison to fail. But it does not.

The difference in your two comparisons is that the non-Unicode comparison, *when using a SQL Server collation (i.e. one with a name starting with `SQL_`)*, is *not* using Unicode comparison rules, whereas if you were using a Windows collation, it would use the same comparison rules for both Unicode and non-Unicode comparisons.

The SQL Server collations, when comparing or sorting non-Unicode data, use a set of obsolete rules (Microsoft refers to these rules as "Sort Orders") that are far more limited than the Unicode rules. These obsolete rules should not set expectations (unless your use-case requires that legacy behavior).

To put it differently, when working with Unicode data, regardless of Windows or non-Windows collation, Unicode sorting and comparison rules are used. Likewise, when working with *non*-Unicode data, IF you are using a *Windows* collation, it will be the Unicode sorting and comparison rules that are used. However, when working with *non*-Unicode data, IF you are using a *SQL Server* collation, then the simplistic Sort Orders will be used for sorting and comparison.

So, what's the difference between Unicode rules and Sort Orders, and which one is "correct"? Well, we need to first look into *why* (linguistically), and *how* (technically), "**ß**" equates to "**ss**".

##### WHY

According to the Wikipedia article for [ß](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)

> In German orthography, the letter **ß**, called **Eszett** (IPA: [ɛsˈtsɛt]) or **scharfes S** (IPA: [ˌʃaʁfəs ˈʔɛs], "sharp S"), represents the /s/ phoneme in Standard German when following long vowels and diphthongs. The letter-name *Eszett* combines the names of the letters of ⟨s⟩ (*Es*) and ⟨z⟩ (*Zett*) in German. The character's Unicode names in English are **sharp s** and **eszett**. The *Eszett* letter is used only in German, and can be typographically replaced with the double-s digraph ⟨ss⟩, if the ß-character is unavailable. In the 20th century, the ß-character was replaced with ss in the spelling of Swiss Standard German (Switzerland and Liechtenstein), while remaining Standard German spelling in other varieties of the German language.

##### HOW

Unicode collating is far more complex than the simple Sort Order mappings and allows for a variety of sorting / comparison rules. This includes "expansions", which will translate a character such as "**ß**" into two Latin "s" characters (i.e. "**ss**").

Expansions are *not* something that the non-Unicode Sort Order functionality can do. Not even the two German Sort Orders can make this comparison:

```sql
SELECT 'German-PhoneBook: 1141' WHERE 'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC1141_CP1_CS_AS;
SELECT 'German-PhoneBook: 273' WHERE 'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE SQL_EBCDIC273_CP1_CS_AS;
```

returns no rows.

##### CORRECTNESS

Given the above info, we can see that: **A**) "ß == ss" *is* a valid linguistic comparison (at least in German), **B**) this comparison can be made using Unicode rules (which is why the comparison succeeds when working with Unicode data as well as non-Unicode data *using a Windows Collation*), and **C**) the comparison cannot be made when working with non-Unicode data *using a SQL Server Collation*.

So, why does **ß == ss**, even when using a non-German collation? And, *should* it be this way?

Rather than having a distinct set of rules per each locale (i.e. the Sort Order approach), Unicode collating starts with a baseline default set of rules that govern all locales. This default set of rules covers US English plus rules from most/all other locales. If a particular locale needs a different rule, it can override the defaults. This is how, even if you are using a Hebrew, Chinese, etc collation (i.e. languages that do not use Latin characters), comparisons operating on English characters will still work correctly for the US English rules.

The "rule" allowing **ß** to equal **ss** is a default rule, and *only* the Hungarian Technical locale overrides this rule. This is why  **ß** is equal to **ss** for *all* non-binary Windows collations that are *not* "Hungarian Technical".

##### EXPECTATIONS

While **ß** is not an English character, having it equate to **ss** is just as valid or invalid as any other rule for non-English languages when using characters not found in the culture of the collation being used.

Given that the Unicode rules are *far* more accurate for capturing the complexities of most (all?) languages, *and* that the older Sort Order approach is too simplistic and obsolete, I'm willing to accept the approach taken by Unicode. In other words, I would not set my expectations by the Sort Order behavior (again, only seen when working with non-Unicode data using a SQL Server collation, and only existing for backwards compatibility). The Unicode rules should been seen as "expected", and the Sort Order behavior should be regarded as deficient (i.e. "sucky").

##### EXTRA

This is why it's preferred to use the newer Windows collations (and quite unfortunate that SQL Server *still* uses `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` as the default for new installations on OSes using the US English locale).

To see the difference with your sample data, just add the following to your 2nd `SELECT` statement:

```sql
,
            case when @scharfess  = @ss COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS 
                 then 'Latin1_General_CI_AS : Strings match'
                 else 'Latin1_General_CI_AS : Strings do not match'
            end;
```

And you will get returned:

```
Latin1_General_CI_AS : Strings match
```

Another difference between the obsolete behavior and Unicode behavior, even when using non-Unicode strings, can be see in the following example, which only returns a row of "2":

```sql
SELECT 1 WHERE 'æ' = 'ae' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
SELECT 2 WHERE 'æ' = 'ae' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see the details for your collation using [`sys.fn_helpcollations`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-helpcollations-transact-sql):

```
SELECT 
    C.[description]
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations() AS C
WHERE
    C.[name] = N'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS';
```

This returns:

```
Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, 
   kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode Data, 

SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Code Page 1252 for non-Unicode Data
```

Notice the **different rules** applied to Unicode and non-Unicode data.

The documentation linked above also says:

> SQL Server supports Windows collations. SQL Server also supports a limited number (<80) of collations called SQL Server collations, that were developed before SQL Server supported Windows collations. SQL Server collations are still supported for backward compatibility, but shouldn't be used for new development work. For more information about Windows collations, see [Windows Collation Name (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql). For more information about collations, see [Collation and Unicode Support](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support).

The fact that 'ß' and 'ss' do not compare equal using *SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Code Page 1252* is a historical limitation maintained for backwards compatibility. It applies to non-Unicode data only.